# Does API.AI output its result in XML format

Tags: xml, dialogflow-es

I want to know if API.AI has a way of outputting its input in a human readable format or even a simple XML that you can pass onto others?

Comment: Could you clarify what does "way of outputting its input" mean? Any example?

Comment: I mean something like the JSON which is created during API.AI chat process but in a human readable format such as XML.

Answer (score 0):

Dialogflow ([formerly API.AI](https://blog.dialogflow.com/post/apiai-new-name-dialogflow-new-features/)) currently only provides JSON responses.

Dialogflow has a [webhook API](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment) to fulfill Dialogflow agent.  You could take the JSON send to your webhook and transform it into XML or another "human readable" format.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.So I should read about fulfillment.